# Why can't I publish my layers using OpenGEO explorer plugin?

Tags: geoexplorer, boundless-suite

Like in the image, the publish & other commands are not enabled.

[image]

Comment: Did you connect to Geoserver with Geoserver catalogs (first one on the list form your image)?

Comment: @Roman I've tried that. Got an error message "Warning: Could not connect to the catalog at that URL". I've created an URL in geoserver like localhost/geoserver/web/test and used that url in the Gerserver catalog. Am i missing something ?

Comment: I have connection with URL: http://localhost:8080/geoserver try something like that

Comment: @Roman It worked. Thanks. Two things 1) Changed the url to localhost:8080/geoserver 2) Password, i've changed the default one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum up comments, answer to your question:

To connect to GeoServer from QGIS installed with OpenGeoSuite you have to install OpenGeo Explorer plugin first.
Before you can publish layers or styles, you have to connect to GeoServer instance by option: 'GeoServer catalogs'. When doing OpenGeo Suite default install, you should put in URL field: `http://localhost:8080/geoserver`
Default login for GeoServer is `admin` and password is `geoserver`.